# arrayformula results go into next column after hitting array constraint and so on, in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

So what I need is after reaching the limit on array_costraint, I want to continue the result into the next column, is that possible?

Here is what I have at the moment

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER('Application Details.'!$B19:$B80,'Application Details.'!$E19:$E80="America")),25,1)
```

or if its possible to do the arrayformula results horizontally then continue to the next row and so on.

Here is my sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XaAm42slGIHuf6K9_Z3N_ddlbsLZLp7mUl8EN_Igbo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Agreed. Formulas are written around specifics, and we don't have those yet. Sharing a link to a spreadsheet is the most efficient way to get those specifics across quickly.

Comment: sorry, here's a sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16XaAm42slGIHuf6K9_Z3N_ddlbsLZLp7mUl8EN_Igbo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with one do you need, but here there are.

Vertical filling (sheet **V AMERICA** in your example table):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(VLOOKUP(
    TRANSPOSE(
      SEQUENCE(
        ROUNDUP(COUNTIF('Application No.'!D2:D, "America") / 25),
        25
      )
    ),
    {
      SEQUENCE(COUNTIF('Application No.'!D2:D, "America")),
      FILTER(
        'Application No.'!B2:B,
        'Application No.'!D2:D = "America"
      )
    },
    2,
  ))
)
```

[image]

Horizontal filling (sheet **H AMERICA** in your example table):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(VLOOKUP(
    SEQUENCE(
      ROUNDUP(COUNTIF('Application No.'!D2:D, "America") / 25),
      25
    ),
    {
      SEQUENCE(COUNTIF('Application No.'!D2:D, "America")),
      FILTER(
        'Application No.'!B2:B,
        'Application No.'!D2:D = "America"
      )
    },
    2,
  ))
)
```

[image]